# Data manipulation with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, join

Sorry for the extremely vague title, I honestly have no idea how to formulate my question accurately. I need some help with writing a query for two tables.

The tables are named **subject** and **assignment** and they look like this:

**Subject**

```
subjectcode | subjectname         | classcode
---------------------------------------------
BAC3000     | Bachelorassignment  | IS3
DAT1000     | Databasetechonlogy  | IS1
INF1000     | Informationsystems  | IS1
LED2000     | IT-leadership       | IS2
OBJ2000     | OOP                 | IS2
PRG3000     | Applied programming | IS3
```

**Assignment**

```
subjectcode | number | deadline
-------------------------------------
DAT1000     | 1      | 2020-10-20
DAT1000     | 2      |
INF1000     | 1      | 2020-10-30
INF1000     | 2      |
```

I need to write a query that outputs all subjectcodes and the *amount of assignments* that subject has. The output should like this:

```
subjectcode | numberofassignment
--------------------------------
BAC3000     | 0  
DAT1000     | 2  
INF1000     | 2  
LED2000     | 0       
OBJ2000     | 0               
PRG3000     | 0
```

I have tried creating views, joining the tables and using count in different ways but no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `BAC3000` does not exists in the Assignment table ??

Comment: `DAT1000` does exist, Twice, but your example read `0` ??

Comment: Examples are a great idea and add clarity to a question, but they really should make sense otherwise they just add confusion

Comment: Sorry, I messed up BAC3000 assignment. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `count()` and left join

```
   select s.subjectcode ,count(number) as numberofassignment from
   Subject s left join Assignment a 
   on s.subjectcode=a.subjectcode 
   group by s.subjectcode
```

Comment: I got this error: #1052 - Column 'subjectcode' in field list is ambiguous. But fixed it by adding "a.subjectcode".

Comment: My first comment was wrong, but you got it right. Meant "s.subjectcode".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but when you want to count the number of assigments to the subjectcode, you can use this statement. You don't need a `join` for this, you can use a subquery instead.

```
select 
 subjectcode,
 (select count(*) from Assignment where subjectcode = s.subjectcode) as numberofassignment
from 
 Subject s
```

Answer (score 0):

With the data you've provided, there is no way the result would look exactly like that. But according to your request, something like this would do the work:

```
SELECT s.subjectcode, count(1) as numberofassignment FROM subject s
LEFT JOIN assignment a
    ON s.subectcode = a.subjectcode
GROUP BY s.subjectcode
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in MySQL:

```
select subjectcode, (select count(*) from Assignment where subjectcode=s.subjectcode)  
from Subject s
```